# Game score in Android (java)

Tags: java, android

So I'm doing an Android game for an assignment resit. This is not my first app but it is my first game. I've never been that much of an expert and quite frankly this is hard for me. I hope someone here can help.

I actually have two problems to add a score (I sincerely hope it's not too much). The thing is, I want to display it in a TextView. When the Sprite "bad" is hit, I want the score to increase by 1.

My first problem is that said TextView doesn't appear on my activity even when I'm not putting anything else than text in it. I tried to put it in LinearLayout, or change some parameters for its position, but I didn't find any other helpful thing on internet.

My second problem is for the score, which even if I can't see it, probably doesn't work. I found some helps saying to put a JPanel or JLabel but I don't think this is what I need. I tried a simple thing where I just made it an int that increases in the isHit and then displays it on the page. But it doesn't display anything, and the program took the bad habit of crashing before I can't even do anything when I have these written in the code.

I don't actually know which other page would be useful, so here is my GameView.java, if any other might be needed, please tell me.

```
package com.example.proprietaire.assignmentna2;
import com.example.proprietaire.assignmentna2.R;
import com.example.proprietaire.assignmentna2.Sprite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private int x = 0, xSpeed = 1;
private Bitmap bmp;
Thread thread = null;
volatile boolean running = false;
static final long FPS = 10;
private long lastClick;
private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private List<Sprite> sprites2 = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>();
private Bitmap bmpSmoke;
int score = 0;


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {


        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            running = false;
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            createSprites();
            running = true;
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                   int width, int height) {
        }
    });

    bmpSmoke = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smoke);
}

private void createSprites() {
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad));
    sprites2.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good));
}

private Sprite createSprite(int resource) {
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    return new Sprite(this, bmp);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
        temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
    }
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites2) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while (running) {

        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (getHolder()) {
                onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick> 300) {
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
                if (sprite.isHit(event.getX(), event.getY())) {

                    sprites.remove(sprite);
                    temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpSmoke));
                    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad));
                    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad));
                    sprites2.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good));

                    score++;

                    break;
                }

                //TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                //String s = "" + score;
                //textView.setText((new Integer(score)).toString(Integer.parseInt(s)));
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is GameActivity.java

```
package com.example.proprietaire.assignmentna2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    GameView GV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GV = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(GV);
    }
}
```

The xml for the game is a simple TextView without any special thing added.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems ok on first glance, but as this entire class is basically still a view, you will want to add your textview next to your SurfaceView, not inside of it. Can you show me the class in which you add the class GameView (the SurfaceView) to the main layout?

Comment: Do you mean my GameActivity? (I'm lost today) I will edit the main post.

Comment: Well I have no idea what you named your "main" class. I'm referring to the class which initiates the `GameView` and adds that instance to some "main" layout such that it is visible on your screen =)

Comment: I think this is what you are talking about? The class linked automatically to my xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked some of my old code when I was making my own game, I made a dummy `.xml` file with nothing but a `RelativeLayout` in it. So your `GameActivity would look something like this:

```
private TextView tv;
private GameView gv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dummyXml);

        initializeGameView();
}
```

From this point on, you can play around with your `GameView` and your `TextView`. I will give an example of the start:

```
private void initializeGameView(){    
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_dummy_xml);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    //Layout stuff
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //add more stuff, play around with whatever you want to do here
    gv = new GameView();
    ll.addView(gv);

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(gv.getScore());
    ll.addView(tv);

    //Finally, don't forget to add the linear layout to the relative layout
    rl.addView(ll);
}
```

Add a `getScore()` method to your `GameView` class or alternatively in a more elegant location :P

If you still have questions (after you've tried and tried and tried), feel free to ask ahead! =)

**EDIT:**
Updated code example with init of the TextView `tv`. If you want to update the textview you added at any point, add a method toughly similar to this one:

```
public void updateTextViewScore(){
    tv.setText(gv.getScore());
}
```

I made the `GameView` and `TextView` variables global, therefore you can access them in any method you wish.

You probably want to call this method (thus update the textview) inside the game loop e.g. whenever the score changes.

Good luck! Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: ...sorry for the delay. I tried and tried (and tried, even tried something else, reason why I didn't answer for that long). Problem is it doesn't know what the "yourTextView" in your example is, no matter what I put to replace it. So I can't test anything.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope the extra information is of use, otherwise I will be needing your "complete" code, including xmls and stuff. But this example should provide you with enough knowledge. Note that you may need to add some layout parameters to the textview and linearlayout as they probably look messed up at the moment.

Comment: Had to adapt/add a few things, but it worked! Thank you! :)